# Does a bounded function in $[a,b]$ with partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ has always distinguished points for Riemann sum so lower sum and Riemann sum equals?

Tags: calculus, integration

Does a bounded function in interval $[a,b]$ with partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ has always distinguished points for Riemann sum so lower sum and Riemann sum equals?

My first thought was that the statement is not true. from those following thoughts I made this conclude:

$*$ The lower sum contains the infimum of the function in each interval of the partition

$*$ Infimum doesn't have be be a value in a function.

$*$ Riemann sum contains only values of the function in each interval of the partition.

The problem is that I did not managed to find an example. So therefore, I'm not sure if I'm right.

Comment: Consider something like $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1, 1] \setminus \{0\}$ with $f(0)=1$. Fix a partition $P$. We have a strict inequality for the lower sum and Riemann sum in the subinterval containing $0$.

Comment: Why do you think a Riemann sum could equal a lower sum (or an upper sum when you are aware that supremum / infimum (related to upper, lower sum)  are not necessarily function values (related to Riemann sum). What is guaranteed is that one can get a Riemann sum arbitrarily close to a given upper or a lower sum because function values can get arbitrarily close to supremum /infimum